# Google Slide API : Add Shape and Center Text Align

Tags: java, google-slides-api

How do I set Text Alignment Center in a Shape `InsertTextRequest` using Google Slides API?

```
    requests.add(new Request()
            .setCreateShape(new CreateShapeRequest()
                    .setObjectId(elementRandomString)
                    .setShapeType("RECTANGLE")
                    .setElementProperties(new PageElementProperties()
                            .setPageObjectId(this.pageObjectId)
                            .setSize(new Size()
                                    .setHeight(ptHeight)
                                    .setWidth(ptWidth))
                            .setTransform(new AffineTransform()
                                    .setScaleX(1.0)
                                    .setScaleY(1.0)
                                    .setTranslateX(xLocation)
                                    .setTranslateY(yLocation)
                                    .setUnit("PT")))));

    if (shapeModel.textModel != null && shapeModel.textModel.textValue != null) {
        requests.add(new Request()
                .setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
                        .setObjectId(elementRandomString)
                        .setText("BOOK")));
    }
```

The last line, we set the text; want to center Text in the middle.

[image: Center align in rectangle]

It was not specified in resources below.

**Resources:**

https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/add-shape

[Java Insert Text Request](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/slides/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/slides/v1/model/InsertTextRequest.html#setInsertionIndex-java.lang.Integer-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the `alignment` using [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#inserttextrequest).
You can update the `alignment` under paragraph styles using the [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateparagraphstylerequest) message in a call to [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate).

### Sample Request Body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateParagraphStyle": {
        "objectId": "gc9072fb39b_0_5",
        "style": {
          "alignment": "CENTER"
        },
        "fields": "alignment"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Applicable Java Code:**

```
requests.add(new Request()
        .setUpdateParagraphStyle(new UpdateParagraphStyleRequest()
                .setObjectId(elementRandomString)
                .setFields("*")
                .setStyle(new ParagraphStyle()
                        .setAlignment("CENTER"))));
```

### Output:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

### References:

- [Updating text style](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/text#updating_text_style)
- [Updating paragraph style](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/text#updating_paragraph_style)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thank you for updating it with a sample code as well. I wasn't able to provide one due to lack of environment platform available on my end :)

Comment: do you possible know the answer for this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795794/google-slides-api-able-to-use-hexadecimal-to-set-colors